# Azure AD Login flow to Blazor Server application require admin approval

Tags: authentication, azure-active-directory, openid-connect

"I have developed a Blazor Server application with Azure AD authorization out of the box. When I log in using my developer account, it works seamlessly. However, when I attempt to log in with another account, I encounter a prompt requesting admin approval.
[admin approval](https://i.stack.imgur.com/343Nv.png)

Could someone please point out where I went wrong? I added the regular user to the app registration and assigned the admin role in the associated enterprise registration. Can someone assist me by explaining what steps I should take next?

Answer (score 0):

1. go to Azure AD -> App
2. go to API permission
3. update the "Status" to Granted for [Domain]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SZBh0.jpg)